# How can I reply to a post in a website using requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Im trying to log-in into a next door using Requests. But I still can't log-in + I want to post a picture with a comment.

anyone can help?

```
import requests
url = "https://nextdoor.com/login/?ucl=1"
username = "myusename"
password = "password" 
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password), verify=False)
```

Comment: Requests isn't really meant to be used interactive like that. Is there no photo upload APIs?

Comment: Check what is `auth` in [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/#requests.request).

Comment: the page is most probably not running with basic auth ... look if they got an API or use a "virtual browser" like beautifulsoup to fill/trigger the right actions until done. check the ToC if they allow this.